# System Verilog Bus Routing

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

In system verilog, I know you can route a partial bus with array[15:8] as a way to split lanes.  Is there any way to do this in a non continuous way.  For example, lane 2,3,8,9 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to Enze Chi way is to use concatenation:

```
wire [3:0] a;
assign a = {b[9:8],b[3],b[2]};
```

Comment: Thankyou, I thought that was for array defining, not bus routing.

Comment: The {...} operator just 'glues' bits or vectors together. Beware of the size of the values inside the brackets. e.g. a constant '3' will add 32 bits!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect the in any way:

For example:

```
 assign a[0] = b[2];
 assign a[1] = b[3];
 assign a[3:2] = b[9:8];
```

Comment: Thankyou, I thought that was for array defining, not bus routing.